# Rails/Ruby: Is there a backbone gem in that doesn't generate coffeescript files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, rubygems

Not sure if this question belongs on stackoverflow....

I'm trying to follow along with Ryan Bates Railscast on Backbone.js. He uses a gem 'backbone-on-rails' that generates coffeescript files. Even if I copy the code exactly as he has it, I'm getting all sorts of weird errors (INDENT errors) and the code's just not working even though, as I said, I'm being very careful about the spaces.

On several occasions, I was able to fix a problem by retyping the code exactly as I had it!

My productivity, already slow, has now ground to a halt using coffeescript, so I'm wondering if there's another backbone.js gem that doesn't use coffee script

For example, here's another error message I've got even though there's no indent and I didn't copy the code from the internet.

```
Error: Parse error on line 2: Unexpected 'INDENT'
```

Another example, the handleError function is supposed to be triggered on an error (and alert message) trying to create an entry. It works on the RailsCast but not in my application.

```
createEntry: (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    attributes = name: $('#new_entry_name').val()
    @collection.create attributes,
      success: -> $('#new_entry')[0].reset()
      error: @handleError

  handleError: (entry, response) ->
    if response.status == 422
      errors = $.parseJSON(response.responseText).errors
      for attribute, messages of errors
        alert "#{attribute} #{message}" for message in messages
```

Comment: Aside: make sure you are either using tabs or two-spaces to signify a tab. When copying code from the internet, this can be frustrating as code you think is part of a function is really it's own thing b/c (for example) you used spaces and the code you pasted use tabs.

Comment: Why do you need a gem at all? You'd be much better off doing all of this stuff by hand while learning or you'll end up with a pile of magic that you don't understand.

Comment: @muistooshort that'd be nice but I don't even know where to begin. I'm assuming the gem installed some backbone stuff in the backend and since I don't know what it is i don't know how to do it by hand.

Comment: You could begin by looking for Backbone tutorials that use localStorage, that way you can leave Rails out of it completely until you know how Backbone works. You can also play around on jsfiddle (here's a fiddle that already has all the Backbone stuff included: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/RRXnK/), jsfiddle also supports CoffeeScript (look under *Panels* in the sidebar).

Comment: But, I'm notice that the documentation says "* Generates CoffeeScript (default) or JavaScript" , how can I generate javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most popular Backbone.js gem for Rails is this: https://github.com/codebrew/backbone-rails. It does not provide functionality for generating Backbone apps in native JavaScript.

You can use the runner-up gem at https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails if you'd like to generate a Backbone app in JavaScript. Simply run the following commands:

- Add `gem 'backbone-on-rails'` to your `Gemfile`
- `bundle install`
- `rails generate backbone:install -j`
- `rails generate backbone:scaffold user -j`

I highly encourage you to learn CoffeeScript, though. Once you nail the syntax down, you'll be able to develop client-side apps at an increasingly rapid rate.

Comment: The codebrew on rails dude seems to have retired? It no longer provides cutting edge backbone, which is a problem. This mimic is the solution: https://github.com/westonplatter/railsy_backbone

Answer (score 8):

In case someone finds this question through Google.

```
# Generate JavaScript
rails generate backbone:install --javascript
```

Source: [backbone-on-rails README](https://github.com/meleyal/backbone-on-rails/blob/master/README) under *Tricks*